# not getting data when using scripted dataset in rcp designer

Tags: birt

This is my Java code line which I am using to pass the data into a birt task:

```
activityReportTask.addScriptableJavaObject("activitybean", activityBeanList);
```

Now I am using rcp designer to create the `*.rptdesign` file for this data, there I'm using the following script in open and in fetch:

### for open:

```
activities = activitybean;
totalrows = activities.size();
currentrow = 0;
cumulativeDistance = 0;
```

### for fetch:

```
if (currentrow >= totalrows){
 return false;
}

bean = activities.get(currentrow);
cumulativeDistance = cumulativeDistance +  bean.getDistance(); 
dataSetRow["time"] = bean.getTime();
dataSetRow["speed"] = bean.getSpeed();
dataSetRow["latitude"] = bean.getLatitude();
dataSetRow["longitude"] = bean.getLongitude();
dataSetRow["distance"] = bean.getDistance();
dataSetRow["cumulativeDistance"] = cumulativeDistance;
dataSetRow["place"] = bean.getPlace();
currentrow = currentrow+1;
return true;
```

but when I try to preview  the report, I'm getting this error:

The following items have errors:

```
ReportDesign (id = 1): 
+ There are errors evaluating script "activities = activitybean;
totalrows = activities.size();
currentrow = 0;
cumulativeDistance = 0;":
{1}. 
Error.ScriptEvaluationError ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "activities = activitybean;
totalrows = activities.size();
currentrow = 0;
cumulativeDistance = 0;":
{1}.
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DataSetScriptExecutor.handleJS(DataSetScriptExecutor.java:219)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleOpen(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:88)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSetRuntime.open(ScriptDataSetRuntime.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor$CustomDataSet.open(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:223)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1094)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:232)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1876)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:920)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
 at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
 at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:126)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A BIRT exception occurred: Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "activitybean" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN(). See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "activitybean" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException.wrap(DataException.java:118)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:1005)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:76)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:90)
 ... 72 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "activitybean" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:303)
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:102)
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:1001)
 ... 74 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "activitybean" is not defined. (#1)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3717)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1758)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1697)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c18._c1(:1)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c18.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10._c0(:0)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.exec()
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:95)
 ... 76 more

     + There are errors evaluating script "if(currentrow >= totalrows){
 return false;
}

bean = activities.get(currentrow);
cumulativeDistance = cumulativeDistance +  bean.getDistance(); 
dataSetRow["time"] = bean.getTime();
dataSetRow["speed"] = bean.getSpeed();
dataSetRow["latitude"] = bean.getLatitude();
dataSetRow["longitude"] = bean.getLongitude();
dataSetRow["distance"] = bean.getDistance();
dataSetRow["cumulativeDistance"] = cumulativeDistance;
dataSetRow["place"] = bean.getPlace();
currentrow = currentrow+1;
return true;":
{1}. 
Error.ScriptEvaluationError ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "if(currentrow >= totalrows){
 return false;
}

bean = activities.get(currentrow);
cumulativeDistance = cumulativeDistance +  bean.getDistance(); 
dataSetRow["time"] = bean.getTime();
dataSetRow["speed"] = bean.getSpeed();
dataSetRow["latitude"] = bean.getLatitude();
dataSetRow["longitude"] = bean.getLongitude();
dataSetRow["distance"] = bean.getDistance();
dataSetRow["cumulativeDistance"] = cumulativeDistance;
dataSetRow["place"] = bean.getPlace();
currentrow = currentrow+1;
return true;":
{1}.
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DataSetScriptExecutor.handleJS(DataSetScriptExecutor.java:219)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:130)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSetRuntime.fetch(ScriptDataSetRuntime.java:103)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor$CustomDataSet.fetch(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:260)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.OdiAdapter.fetch(OdiAdapter.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:105)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.ExpandableRowResultSet.next(ExpandableRowResultSet.java:63)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.populateData(SmartCacheHelper.java:316)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.initInstance(SmartCacheHelper.java:285)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.getResultSetCache(SmartCacheHelper.java:246)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCache.<init>(SmartCache.java:72)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassUtil.populateOdiResultSet(PassUtil.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassUtil.pass(PassUtil.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.doSinglePass(PassManager.java:214)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.prepareDataSetResultSet(PassManager.java:97)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.pass(PassManager.java:128)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.populateResultSet(PassManager.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.ResultSetPopulator.populateResultSet(ResultSetPopulator.java:198)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.CachedResultSet.<init>(CachedResultSet.java:192)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.CandidateQuery.execute(CandidateQuery.java:106)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:226)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1094)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:232)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1876)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:920)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
 at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
 at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:126)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A BIRT exception occurred: Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "currentrow" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_FETCH(). See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "currentrow" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_FETCH()
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException.wrap(DataException.java:118)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:1005)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:76)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:90)
 ... 88 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "currentrow" is not defined. (#1)
 Script source: , line: 0, text:
__bm_FETCH()
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:303)
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:102)
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:1001)
 ... 90 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "currentrow" is not defined. (#1)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3717)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1758)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1697)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c25._c1(:1)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c25.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c0(:0)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call()
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.exec()
 at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:95)
 ... 92 more

     + data.engine.BadFetchScriptReturnType 
data.engine.BadFetchScriptReturnType ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: data.engine.BadFetchScriptReturnType
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptExecutor.addException(ScriptExecutor.java:158)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:920)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
 at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
 at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: data.engine.BadFetchScriptReturnType
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:140)
 ... 86 more
```

Can anyone help figure out the cause and resolution for these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't "played" with java objects in birt but when I see it correctly the reference to the activitybean does not work. Since addScriptableJavaObject is deprecated try to add the list via:

```
HashMap hm = config.getAppContext(); hm.put( "activitybean", activityBeanList );
```

And then access it in the report via

```
appContext = reportContext.getAppContext();
activities = appContext.get("activitybean");
```

If this does not work, there is a great tutorial on using java object in birt from Lars Vogel: [EclipseBirt](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseBIRT/article.html)

Good luck!

Comment: well first of all thanks for answering the question..but here my question is that you used here hashmap but i am using birt task for that and moreover i am loading a class into that by using: activityReportTask.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY, ActivityBean.class.getClassLoader()); and then i used  addScriptableJavaObject. So if i use this here then can i access it in report desingner directly. what is this appcontext and reportContext are there in report. How this report designer will identify these objects..??

Comment: Hi. Actually I don't really get your problem...sorry. Have you tried the way I described or do you wanna stick to "your" solution? If you add your class/jar to the classpath (either by adding the jar to the lib path or via the resource section in the report) you should have access to it. Additionally you can add jars to the Designer via Eclipse settings "Report-Design -> Classpath". What exactly is that activityBeanList? Can't you simply instantiate it in the open() method of the ds?

Comment: Hi, i am really grateful for your quick response and sorry that i couldn't reply soon. i have tried your way too, but in designer i was getting the same error while i was trying to preview my report. it was showing "activitybean" is not defined. That means it is not recognizing the java object in java script. but the same code is working fine in older version of our product.
You asked for activityBeanList, well it is a collection having list of data which i want to display in report. It is getting all the required data in it, but in report designer data is not coming. i am not getting why?

Comment: even though if i use deprecated method it should work atleast as it is working fine in older version.
even right now i am even getting report parameters in my report those too i am passing through same java file by using another method. Is i am missing anything while creating script dataset. Moreover i have been to http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseBIRT/article.html but it is using the function with string parameter i.e. string only. In report also they are using another way to access the data from java object.
any king of help would be highly appreciable.
Thanks,
vikS

Comment: Hi, i used your way literally and got this in logs: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file file:/C:/Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/webapps/birt-runtime-2_2_1_1/reports/ActivityRepor
t.rptdesign has error and can not be run.
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReportDesign(ReportEngineHelper.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReportDesign(ReportEngineHelper.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReportDesign(ReportEngineHelper.java:125)

Comment: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.openReportDesign(ReportEngine.java:239)
        at com.i10n.fleet.util.BIRTEngine.createTask(BIRTEngine.java:84)
        at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportOperations.ExportActivityReport(ExportReportOperations.java:111)
        at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportOperations.generateActivityReport(ExportReportOperations.java:67)
        at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportsController.processRequest(ExportReportsController.java:122)

Comment: at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportsController.handleRequestInternal(ExportReportsController.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.CascadedFormController.handleRequest(CascadedFormController.java:47)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)

Comment: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at

Comment: Caused by: Error.DesignFileException.SYNTAX_ERROR - 5 errors found!
1.)  ( line = 15, tag = value)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.WRONG_SIMPLE_LIST_TYPE, messag
e : No such an element property is simple list type.)
2.)  ( line = 28, tag = value)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.WRONG_SIMPLE_LIST_TYPE, messag
e : No such an element property is simple list type.)

Comment: 3.)  ( line = 41, tag = value)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.WRONG_SIMPLE_LIST_TYPE, messag
e : No such an element property is simple list type.)
4.)  ( line = 54, tag = value)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.WRONG_SIMPLE_LIST_TYPE, messag
e : No such an element property is simple list type.)
5.)  ( line = 7, tag = property)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.UNDEFINED_PROPERTY, message

Comment: : The property "bidiLayoutOrientation" is not defined.) i used what u have mention here. dont know why this error is coming. any help would be appreciable..

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. This is getting too deep and goes way beyond my knowledge. If you can send me a short example report design I might try to run it from here. But I think the better resource to ask is over at birt-exchange.They answer really quick and helped me with all my problems. Sorry and good luck.